# Replace special characters in Body Issue

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, url-rewriting, special-characters

When my page is load then special characters are converted.

```
Å to Ã¥
ø to Ã  
More also
```

I don't want these to be change. What should i do.
Is there any option to edit 
in htaccess file. When i remove my htccess file code then these characters are not changed.

**My htccess file code:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Pagination Pages Url

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Spare-og-Laresenter(?:\.php)?\?tpages=([^&]+)&page=([^&\s]+) [NC]

    RewriteRule ^ Spare-og-Laresenter/%1/%2? [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^Spare-og-Laresenter/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ Spare-og-Laresenter.php?tpages=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

#Postdetail.php page url

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blogg(?:\.php)?\?postid=([^\&\ ]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ blogg/%1? [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^blogg/([^\&\ ]+)/?$ blogg.php?postid=$1 [L,QSA]

#Spare-og-Laresenter.php page url for category

 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Spare-og-Laresenter(?:\.php)?\?catname=([^\&\ ]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ Spare-og-Laresenter/%1? [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^Spare-og-Laresenter/([^\&\ ]+)/?$ Spare-og-Laresenter.php?catname=$1 [L,QSA]

    ## hide .php extension snippet
    # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

    # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have try to use charset in HTAccess:
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

for example:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not defining your charset in the header. Always define the charset to the browser using the meta tags. Use the following tag in your header.

```
<meta charset='UTF-8' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what character encoding your files are using I will assume it is UTF-8.
But to debug you can swap UTF-8 with ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, or other encoding types.

If you provide a link to a sample page we can further diagnose the issue.

You should be able to fix the majority of the issue by adding `AddDefaultCharset` to your .htaccess file under the `Options` setting like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
```

You can alternatively limit the impact by using `AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" .php`
or use a file match like

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
</FilesMatch>
```

if you do not want to affect other files.

Also ensure your PHP files do not have an additional `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=---')`;

You should also check your browser's character encoding setting to ensure it is set to automatic as opposed to ISO-8859-1 or something else.